# 2.1.8 CE - Unable to set attribute set for new product

Tags: magento2, attributes

I have a clean install of Magento CE 2.1.8 and then imported my data from Magento 1.9. Now when I want to add new products on my old attribute sets which were created on M1, page is loading over and over and I got below message in chrome dev tool console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at UiClass.getNewData (dynamic-rows-grid.js:180)
>       at UiClass.initElements (dynamic-rows-grid.js:86)
>       at setNested (objects.js:43)
>       at Object.nested (objects.js:117)
>       at UiClass.set (element.js:301)
>       at updateValue (links.js:57)
>       at Function.notifySubscribers (knockout.js:1103)
>       at Function.observable.valueHasMutated (knockout.js:1300)
>       at UiClass.observable [as recordData] (knockout.js:1285)
>       at setNested (objects.js:43)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I am getting same error and then I found that if you want switch a product from one attribute set to another, the destination attribute set must contain the attributes of the source attribute set in the same attribute group.

So then, I just rearranged the Attributes group and attribute order same as Default Attribute Set then its working like charm.